# Use both integrated and discrete graphics card with different screens?

Tags: linux, laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

Is it possible for an integrated graphics card to handle one screen and a dicrete one
to handle another? If so, how to configure it in Manjaro or Arch Linux?

My motivation is to fully use (achieve the highest possible efficiency) the hardware of my Dell XPS 15 9570 laptop with Linux, which has an UHD Intel® 630 integrated graphics card and also an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Max-Q one. With a monitor connected there are two screens in total.

I realize a classic dual screen GUI in which a desktop spans two screens and parts of a single window may be on both at once might not be feasible. I'd be content with a solution whereby each desktop (nowadays systems usually support multiple, even Windows does) would have a single card assigned. Less preferable would be to have two sessions, possibly for the same user, attached to the screens, with a single windowing system. Two instances of a windowing system – still worse, but if nothing better can be achieved, I'd take it.

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? I mean, why would you need a separate card driving each screen? Would you also want separate X instances? What is the end result you're trying to achieve here for which using each screen with a different card would be the solution?

Comment: I have two graphics cards in the laptop, so I'd like to use them (while plugged, at my desk with a monitor), not have one sitting there for nothing. I believe this would allow the best efficiency and full feature set. No, unless it cannot be avoided, I don't want separate X or anything, I'd like to be able to use it in a way as close to normal dual screen usage as possible, juggling windows between the two.

Comment: That... seems like a very, very inefficient thing to do. You would be powering _two_ cards instead of powering just one and not taking advantage of the ability to switch between them, using whichever is better for the job at hand with something like optimus or bumblebee. It really sounds like you are trying to get the worst of both worlds here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a 2nd card just for the sake of using it is a waste of power. Say you want to visit friends with your partner. Will you drive in one car together or two cars separately so the other one doesn't sit unused in the garage?

That being said: with rare exceptions it's not a matter of configuration, but of physical composition of hardware. It would maybe be more obvious in a desktop that monitors are always driven by the graphics card that they are connected to. (Although rendering may happen on a different GPU.)

There are three possible designs. Neither of them affects the multi-monitor experience. GPUs don't care if there's a window being displayed partially on one screen and partially on the other - it's all just pixels.

## 1. All video outputs connected to the integrated GPU

This is common in laptops with low-end to mid-range dedicated GPUs. Internal display and video outputs are wired to the iGPU. For more demanding programs rendering will happen on the dGPU and rendered frames (fullscreen or windowed) will be sent over to iGPU to be displayed. This setup is optimized for power efficiency with just iGPU being used most of the time.

## 2. Internal display connected to iGPU, outputs connected to dGPU

This is typical for laptops with high-end dedicated GPUs. It exists for basically one reason: to avoid bottlenecking the powerful GPU by limited PCI-e throughput. When rendering happens on a different GPU than the display is connected to, the rendered frames have to be sent over through the PCI-e interface. It will actually use up a significant chunk of its throughout and the more FPS your GPU can produce, the more it will bottleneck itself trying to push them out for displaying.

Connecting external displays directly to the dGPU solves this issue by removing the need to pass rendered frames to the iGPU. Entire bandwidth is available for productive usage and rendered visuals go directly to the display, without passing through the iGPU first.

The first drawback of this setup is that using external displays requires powering on the dGPU, even if you aren't running any graphically intensive programs. However when using external displays you most likely have a power outlet around, so increased power consumption and shortened battery life is not that much of an issue.

The other drawback is that the internal display is still connected to the iGPU for a related reason: to enable using the laptop without powering the dGPU when not running anything that would require its performance. That, however, reintroduces the PCI-e bottleneck issue when eg. gaming on the internal display, because frames are rendered by one GPU and displayed by the other. It's a tradeoff that can't be avoided easily.

## 3. Mux chip

Very few laptop models feature an internal multiplexer that can physically rewire outputs to either iGPU or dGPU by changing a BIOS setting. This lets the user choose to give up power efficiency with less demanding applications for additional performance for graphically intensives ones, or prioritize battery life in desktop apps over extra performance in games. With the mux even the internal display can be switched to run off the dGPU.

This is the rarest setup because it increases cost and complexity while providing no value to the majority of users.

Comment: Is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Max-Q mid-range or high-end?

Comment: @ByteEater Definitely not high-end