# How can I set my internal display to my integrated gpu and all my outputs to my external gpu?

Tags: linux, laptop, multiple-monitors, gpu, external-display

I know a question [like this](https://superuser.com/questions/1762779/use-both-integrated-and-discrete-graphics-card-with-different-screens/1762788#1762788?newreg=0dc6c7d28b524729a5bc886eaa71a1b4) has already been asked, but they only asked if it is possible. I want to know how someone actually does this. In particular, the second option from that question's accepted answer.

My problem is that my laptop has Thunderbolt, but only two PCIe lanes through it. Any configuration I choose that uses my external GPU (Radeon RX 580 in my case) to power my second monitor seems to also loopback and power my internal monitor as well, and checking the pipeline seems to show that it is filled when I do anything on my internal display.

What I *want* is to have my integrated GPU (Dell UHD Graphics 620) process and output my internal display, and my external GPU to process and output my external display. I am not worried about efficiency, I just want to remove the bottleneck from sending data both ways on my Thunderbolt port.

In my attempts, I have tried using egpu-switcher, which works but it caused an angled flickering line on my internal display. It also made it glitch a lot when scrolling a lot of text in any application.

I also tried using Wayland, but a lot of applications on my computer just wouldn't start.

And recently I tried configuring Xorg.conf, but I've only managed to somehow make my computer stop recognizing the external monitor.

I am running Pop OS for my distro. I am willing to switch distros if I have to, but I also want to know how anyone should go about this.
I've been trying to do this off and on for half a year, but I feel like I'm misunderstanding something. Any help would be appreciated. If you need more information, let me know.